# Best practice for using DomContentLoaded in angular2?

Tags: angular

I see numerous examples of Angular2 code bootstrapping with a DomContentLoaded listener:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
});
```

and without:

```
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

I've looked at the docs and it appears to still be a valid thing but no indications with when it should or shouldn't be used.

What are the reasons to use it or not use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no differences between bootstrapping Angular app using first or second approach. The differences is when it is happening.

First approach will wait until `'DOMContentLoaded'` so when all HTML will be parsed by the browser. That should ensure that your `<appModule></appModule>` will be available for Angular JS and it will bootstrap correctly.

Second approach will try to bootstrap it immediately and depending on how it was loaded it might or might not work.

- if loaded in head via simple `<script>` it should fail
- if loaded in head via `<script>` with `defer` attribute it will work (as execution was deferred until HTML was parsed)
- if loaded just before `</body>` it will work as well as HTML was parsed as well (this is a most popular method which is used on Angular tutorial pages)